# Regex for matching text between unescaped underscore

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to replace text which is between underscores with the  tag.
This is what pattern I'm currently using (Link to online tester: [TESTER](https://regex101.com/r/f3uxic/2)):

```
[^\\]?_(([^_]*)[^\\])_
```

This is the result I want to get:

```
_test1_ _test2__test3_ \_test4\_ => <b>test1</b> <b>test2</b><b>test3</b> \_test4\_
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my pattern?

Comment: Try [`(?<!\\)((?:\\{2})*)_([^_\\]*(?:\\.[^_\\]*)*)_`](https://regex101.com/r/f9yleF/1) (to replace with `$1<b>$2</b>`). In PHP, the ``\`` must be defined as ``\\\\`` in the pattern.

Comment: Could you please explain me the first part of the pattern? (?<!\\)((?:\\{2})*)

Comment: That `(?<!\\)((?:\\{2})*)_` part matches an unescaped `_`: any number of double ``\`` symbols that are not preceded with a ``\``. Does it work as expected?

Comment: Yeah it works absolutely great thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
(?<!\\)((?:\\{2})*)_([^_\\]*(?:\\.[^_\\]*)*)_
```

PHP declaration:

```
$pattern = '~(?<!\\\\)((?:\\\\{2})*)_([^_\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^_\\\\]*)*)_~';
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f9yleF/1)

**Details**:

- `(?<!\\)((?:\\{2})*)_` - matches an unescaped `_`: any number of double `\` symbols (see `(?:\\{2})*`, 0+ sequences of two consecutive `\` symbols) that are not preceded with a `\` (`(?<!\\)` negative lookbehind performs this check)
- `([^_\\]*(?:\\.[^_\\]*)*)_` - matches any number of symbols other than `_` or any number of escaped symbols thus only matching up to the first unescaped `_`.

  - `[^_\\]*` - matches 0+ chars other than `\` and `_`
  - `(?:\\.[^_\\]*)*` - 0+ sequences of:

    - `\\.` - any escaped char (if you use `s` DOTALL modifier, even a line break char)
    - `[^_\\]*` - 0+ chars other than `\` and `_`

To use the same approach in JavaScript and other regex engines that do not support a lookbehind, use `(^|[^\\])` group instead of `(?<!\\)`:

```
(^|[^\\])((?:\\{2})*)_([^_\\]*(?:\\.[^_\\]*)*)_
```

And replace with `$1$2<b>$3</b>`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fQxWs0/1).

Comment: is there a way to do it without the negativ look behind? Since I also want to use the same processing for JavaScript functions, and JS doesn't seem to provide that ...

Comment: Yes, there are several ways to emulate a negative lookbehind in JS. I added the JS-compatible solution to the answer.